# ec2 to s3 sync impact on network bandwidth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

When you have multiple ec2 instances in your VPC, does an s3 sync from any of the ec2 instance add to the network overhead of the VPC? This could be either while adding the data on s3 from an ec2 instance or while downloading the data from s3 to any ec2 instance.

So for instance if I've backups on my ec2 instance ebs volumes that I need to store in s3, is it something that I should do only during the non-peak hours when my network bandwidth is not that heavily used by my web servers running on some of these ec2 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only bandwidth-limiting element in AWS is a bandwidth limit placed on each Amazon EC2 instance. The available bandwidth **varies by Instance Type** (Low, Moderate, High).

The bandwidth available to an EC2 instance **will *not* be impacted** by any network traffic taking place on other instances. An Amazon VPC is a virtual network and and does not itself have a bandwidth limit.

For highest performance while copying between EC2 and S3, use a larger instance type and have both the EC2 instance and the S3 bucket **in the same region**.